# Mysql returns duplicate entries in simple join

Tags: mysql, join

I have 2 tables: `course` and `section` as shown in [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d3f671/6)

I need to select the `'starttime' (or null)` for each course's section.
Some courses don't have a 'section' entry.

The query:

```
select section.id, section.course, section.section, IFNULL(schedule.starttime, "null")
from section
join schedule on schedule.courseid = section.course
where course = 3 and section.section > 0
```

returns has many duplicate entries as there are in the joined table.

```
id      course  section IFNULL(schedule.starttime, "null")
7       3       1       1440021600
7       3       1       1440021620
7       3       1       1440021640
8       3       2       1440021600
8       3       2       1440021620
8       3       2       1440021640
9       3       3       1440021600
9       3       3       1440021620
9       3       3       1440021640
```

When I expect:

```
id      course  section IFNULL(schedule.starttime, "null")
7       3       1       1440021600
8       3       2       1440021620
9       3       3       1440021640
10      3       4       null
11      3       5       null
```

I tried different combinations of `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` without success.

Comment: They are not really distnct.. are they? dates are different.

Comment: how are you selecting single date when you have multiple dates? what is the logic?

Comment: @DarkKnight: because it gives the exact same result as above. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d3f671/7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `left join` then use the `schedule.sectionid` and `section.id`

```
select section.id, section.course, section.section, IFNULL(schedule.starttime, "")
from section
LEFT JOIN schedule ON schedule.sectionid = section.id
where course = 3 and section.section > 0;
```

**[SEE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d3f671/31)**

Comment: This works as expected and the join is "cleaner" than Teve's answer. I need to figure out why both queries work.

Comment: @gyc, the only difference of teve's answer is that he added this condition `schedule.courseid = section.course` in which it's just redundant since it has already a filter of `course id` that contains a specific value

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
SELECT section.id, section.course, section.section, IFNULL(schedule.starttime, "null")
FROM section
LEFT JOIN schedule ON schedule.courseid = section.course AND schedule.id = section.section
WHERE course = 3 AND section.section > 0
```

Comment: hmmm, it does return what I want but I don't understand why or if it's the right way to do this. I've never had to do anything like this.

Comment: `left join` to display those records which does not have match in your `section` table;
the extra condition `schedule.id = section.section` is to select the proper `schedule.starttime` value (as I see from your source)